# SharePoint Designer 2013 Page accessing ClientContext issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, jsom, wiki-pages

I have created a new aspx page from SharePoint Designer 2013 and I have following scripts added on my page head section. The page does not belong to any app, it is separate Wiki page, added from SharePoint Designer interface.

[image]

In App.js file I have following code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', 
function (){
 //your code goes here...
 alert('script loaded');
      var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
});
```

When I open page in browser It is giving me following error:
**sp.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webServerRelativeUrl' of undefined**

And I have no idea what I am missing or whats wrong with my code. Please can somebody explain this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: is this an app?

Comment: No this is not an App, its normal aspx page added from SharePoint designer interface.

Comment: Have you done alternate access mapping on the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` instead. something like this

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, "sp.js");

function init() 
{
            this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
            currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
            this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
            this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
```

Comment: I tried this too, but I am getting same error.

Comment: did you try just embed your code in a Script Editor on any page and see if it works or not? Can you share a screen shot of the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove unnecessary script tag from your header which is after `sp.js`

You need to place it before the `runtime.js`

Please check this below given URL.

It is having the same Issue & got the resolution as an answer.

[SP.PageContextInfo.get_webServerRelativeUrl uncaught TypeError](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fbe316d9-387b-47bf-aabc-5d205f5f064d/sppagecontextinfogetwebserverrelativeurl-uncaught-typeerror?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: Did you tried it? Is it working for you?